# Stop Timer Elapsed event on button click

Tags: c#, timer

Here is my Code for calling an event after 1 minute, I have two button one for start and calling elapsed event after every 1 minute and second button for stopping this timer elapsed event to fire.

start Button evnt code is

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        System.Timers.Timer _timer;
                    _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
                    _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Timer Elapsed event

```
     static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
//It works fine it fires after every minute
    }
```

Stop button event code

```
  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//What to do here??
    }
```

I want to stop this timer activity to stop on this button click evnent. what should be code here??

My entire code is

```
public partial class TimerScheduler : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
    //_timer = ;
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `_timer.Stop()`, isn't it?

Comment: Either _timer.Stop() or _timer.Enabled=false

Comment: I tried this 
 System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }
as I click stop button 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. :(

Comment: _timer is null which throws this exception

Comment: Making _timer a local variable of the Click event handler was the clear and obvious mistake.  Move it out of the method so it becomes a field of your class.

Comment: I have placed break point at _timer_Elapsed but it gets called after I press stop button :(

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:** you can Call `Stop()` method of the `Timer`.

```
_timer.Stop();
```

**Solution 2:**  you can Set `Enabled` property of the `Timer` to `false`.

```
_timer.Enabled=false;
```

**Note:** I would suggest calling `Stop()` method.

**Solution 3:**

you are getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception because you have not initialised your timer by clicking on `button1` . so you should not click on `button2` untill unless you click on `button1` as `button1` click event handler contains initialisation code to make your present code to work.

**OR**

I would suggest you to move the `timer` initialisation statement to outside the `Button1` click event handler.

Try This :

```
System.Timers.Timer _timer; 
_timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{           
    _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
    _timer.Enabled = true;
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  _timer.Stop(); 
}
```

Comment: Stop() is just setting Enabled=false so setting Enabled=false will be a little bit faster.

Comment: @Heslacher: i agree with you but i think sometime back `Enabled=false` did not work for me, thats why i suggested `Stop()`.

Comment: I tried this 
 System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }
as I click stop button 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. :(

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi _timer is null which throws this exception

Comment: @user1933955: Check my edited answer with `Solution3`

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi it didnt help me I have pasted this code as I click start button elapsed event fires after  minute and after every  minute it fire itself now I click stop button in which I have pasted _timer.Stop(); but elapsed event keep on firing itself after every 1 minute it didnt stop:(

Comment: @user1933955: what is the code inside the `_timer_Elapsed` event handler?

Comment: there is nothing in that event I have removed all of it for testing purpose and I just placed a break point on this event and this event gets fired after every 1 minute

Comment: Here is my complete code
    static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
    System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
    //_timer = ;
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Enabled = false;
    }